# twitter oAuth for developers wordpress - can't output tweets

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, oauth, widget

I am using a great script called twitter oAuth for developers to create a twitter feed plugin for my wordpress site. The aim is to create a widget where the user can enter their username and number of tweets to display, and that shows in the clients site.

Twitter oAuth for developers creates the following function that is used to display tweets:

```
getTweets($number_of_tweets, $twitter_screenname_to_load);
```

Since I am allowing the user to change the username and no. of tweets, I have changed it to this:

```
$no_of_tweets = $widget['no_of_tweets'];
$twitter_username = $widget['twitter_username'];
$tweets = getTweets($no_of_tweets, ''.$twitter_username.'');
```

Where $widget['no_of_tweets'] and $widget['twitter_username'] are parameters specified by the user.

I have set defaults for this plugin as follows:

```
/* Setup Widget Defaults */
        $this->defaults = array (
            ...
            'twitter_username' => 'skizzar_sites',
            'no_of_tweets' => 3,
            ...
            )
        );
```

So when I load up my plugin, it shows the latest 3 tweets from skizzar_sites - as it should. However, when the user change the number or username, the widget outputs a single random tweet from a random user.

Is there something obviously wrong with the way I have written the function:

```
$tweets = getTweets($no_of_tweets, ''.$twitter_username.'');
```

Here is my full widget code for reference:

```
<?php  /**
 * Layers Twitter Widget
 *
 * This file is used to register and display the Layers widget.
 * http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/
 * 
 * @package Layers
 * @since Layers 1.0.0
 */
if( !class_exists( 'Layers_Twitter_Widget' ) && class_exists( 'Layers_Widget' ) ) {
// http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#widget-class
class Layers_Twitter_Widget extends Layers_Widget {

    /**
    *  1 - Widget construction
    * http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#1-widget-construction
    */
    function Layers_Twitter_Widget(){
        $this->widget_title = __( 'Tweets' , 'layerswp' );
        $this->widget_id = 'tweets';
        $this->post_type = '';
        $this->taxonomy = '';
        $this->checkboxes = array();

        /* Widget settings. */ 
        $widget_ops = array( 
              'classname' => 'obox-layers-' . $this->widget_id .'-widget', 
              'description' => __( 'This widget is used to display your Tweets', 'layerswp')
        );

        /* Widget control settings. */ 
        $control_ops = array( 
              'width' => '660', 
              'height' => NULL, 
              'id_base' => 'layers-widget-' . $this->widget_id 
        );

        /* Create the widget. */ 

        parent::__construct( 'layers' . '-widget-' . $this->widget_id , $this->widget_title, $widget_ops, $control_ops );

        /* Setup Widget Defaults */
        $this->defaults = array (
            'title' => __( 'Twitter Feed', 'layerswp' ),
            'excerpt' => __( 'Display a list of your most recent tweets', 'layerswp' ),
            'twitter_username' => 'skizzar_sites',
            'no_of_tweets' => 3,
            'design' => array(
                'layout' => 'layout-boxed',
                'textalign' => 'text-left',
                'background' => array(
                    'position' => 'center',
                    'repeat' => 'no-repeat'
                ),
                'fonts' => array(
                    'align' => 'text-left',
                    'size' => 'medium',
                    'color' => NULL,
                    'shadow' => NULL
                )
            )
        );

    } // END main function

    /**
    *  2 - Widget form
    * http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#2-widget-form
    * We use regulage HTML here, it makes reading the widget much easier 
    * than if we used just php to echo all the HTML out.
    * 
    */
    function form( $instance ){

    // $instance Defaults
        $instance_defaults = $this->defaults;

        // If we have information in this widget, then ignore the defaults
        if( !empty( $instance ) ) $instance_defaults = array();

        // Parse $instance
        $instance = wp_parse_args( $instance, $instance_defaults );

        extract( $instance, EXTR_SKIP );

        // Design Bar Components
        $design_bar_components = apply_filters(
              'layers_' . $this->widget_id . '_widget_design_bar_components' ,
                  array(
                    'layout',
                    'fonts',
                    'background',
                    'advanced'
                  )
        );

        // Instantiate the Deisgn Bar
        $this->design_bar(
            'side', // CSS Class Name
              array(
                 'name' => $this->get_field_name( 'design' ),
                 'id' => $this->get_field_id( 'design' ),
              ), // Widget Object
             $instance, // Widget Values
             $design_bar_components // Standard Components
        );

        // Build Content Form 
        // http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#content-options-form
        ?>

        <div class="layers-container-large">
            <?php
                $this->form_elements()->header( 
                       array(
                        'title' =>  __( 'Tweets' , 'layerswp' ),
                        'icon_class' => 'post'
                       ) 
                );
            ?>
            <section class="layers-accordion-section layers-content">
                <div class="layers-row layers-push-bottom">

                <p>In order for the twitter widget to work, you will need to set up a twitter app and add your API credentials to the dashboard. Click here to enter your API details.</p>
                <p class="layers-form-item">
                      <?php echo $this->form_elements()->input(
                          array(
                              'type' => 'text',
                              'name' => $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ,
                              'id' => $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ,
                              'placeholder' => __( 'Enter title here' , 'layerswp' ),
                              'value' => ( isset( $title ) ) ? $title : NULL ,
                              'class' => 'layers-text layers-large'
                          )
                      ); ?>
                </p>

                <p class="layers-form-item">
                      <?php echo $this->form_elements()->input(
                          array(
                              'type' => 'rte',
                              'name' => $this->get_field_name( 'excerpt' ) ,
                              'id' => $this->get_field_id( 'excerpt' ) ,
                              'placeholder' => __( 'Short Excerpt' , 'layerswp' ),
                              'value' => ( isset( $excerpt ) ) ? $excerpt : NULL ,
                              'class' => 'layers-textarea layers-large'
                          )
                      ); ?>
                </p>

                <p class="layers-form-item">
                      <?php 
                        echo $this->form_elements()->input(
                          array(
                              'type' => 'text',
                              'name' => $this->get_field_name( 'twitter_username' ) ,
                              'id' => $this->get_field_id( 'twitter_username' ) ,
                              'placeholder' => __( 'Twitter username' , 'layerswp' ),
                              'value' => ( isset( $twitter_username ) ) ? $twitter_username : NULL ,
                              'class' => 'layers-text layers-large'
                          )
                      ); ?>
                </p>

                <p class="layers-form-item">
                    <?php 
                        echo __( 'Number of tweets to show' , 'layerswp' ); 
                        echo $this->form_elements()->input(
                            array(
                                'type' => 'number',
                                'name' => $this->get_field_name( 'no_of_tweets' ) ,
                                'id' => $this->get_field_id( 'no_of_tweets' ) ,
                                'value' => ( isset( $no_of_tweets ) ) ? $no_of_tweets : NULL ,
                                'min' => '1',
                                'max' => '20'
                            )
                    ); ?>
                </p>

                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

    <?php 
    } // Form

    /**
    *  3 - Update Options
    *  http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#3-update-controls 
    */    

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
      if ( isset( $this->checkboxes ) ) {
        foreach( $this->checkboxes as $cb ) {
          if( isset( $old_instance[ $cb ] ) ) {
            $old_instance[ $cb ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ $cb ] );
          }
        } // foreach checkboxes
      } // if checkboxes

      return $new_instance;
    } 


    /**
    *  4 - Widget front end display
    *  http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#4-widget-front-end
    */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        // Turn $args array into variables.
        extract( $args );

        // $instance Defaults
        $instance_defaults = $this->defaults;

        // If we have information in this widget, then ignore the defaults
        if( !empty( $instance ) ) $instance_defaults = array();

        // Parse $instance
        $widget = wp_parse_args( $instance, $instance_defaults );

        // Apply Styling
        // http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#colors-and-font-settings
        layers_inline_styles( '#' . $widget_id, 'background', array( 'background' => $widget['design'][ 'background' ] ) );
        layers_inline_styles( '#' . $widget_id, 'color', array( 'selectors' => array( '.section-title h3.heading' , '.section-title div.excerpt' ) , 'color' => $widget['design']['fonts'][ 'color' ] ) );

        // Apply the advanced widget styling
        $this->apply_widget_advanced_styling( $widget_id, $widget );

        // Generate the widget container class
        // Do not edit
        $widget_container_class = array();
        $widget_container_class[] = 'widget row content-vertical-massive';
        $widget_container_class[] = $this->check_and_return( $widget , 'design', 'advanced', 'customclass' );
        $widget_container_class[] = $this->get_widget_spacing_class( $widget );
        $widget_container_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'layers_post_widget_container_class' , $widget_container_class ) ); 
        /**
        *  Widget Markup
        *  http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#widget-html
        */
        ?> 

        <section class=" <?php echo $widget_container_class; ?>" id="<?php echo $widget_id; ?>">
            <?php if( '' != $this->check_and_return( $widget , 'title' ) ||'' != $this->check_and_return( $widget , 'excerpt' ) ) { ?>
                <div class="container clearfix">    
                    <?php 
                    // Generate the Section Title Classes
                    $section_title_class = array();
                    $section_title_class[] = 'section-title clearfix';
                    $section_title_class[] = $this->check_and_return( $widget , 'design', 'fonts', 'size' );
                    $section_title_class[] = $this->check_and_return( $widget , 'design', 'fonts', 'align' );
                    $section_title_class[] = ( $this->check_and_return( $widget, 'design', 'background' , 'color' ) && 'dark' == layers_is_light_or_dark( $this->check_and_return( $widget, 'design', 'background' , 'color' ) ) ? 'invert' : '' );
                    $section_title_class = implode( ' ', $section_title_class ); ?>

                    <div class="<?php echo $section_title_class; ?>">
                        <?php if( '' != $widget['title'] ) { ?>
                            <h3 class="heading"><?php echo esc_html( $widget['title'] ); ?></h3>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if( '' != $widget['excerpt'] ) { ?>
                            <div class="excerpt"><?php echo $widget['excerpt']; ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            <?php }

            // Begin Post Structure ?>  
            <div class="row <?php echo $this->get_widget_layout_class( $widget ); ?> <?php echo $this->check_and_return( $widget , 'design', 'liststyle' ); ?>">

            <?php //start Twitter output


// draft sample display for array returned from oAuth Twitter Feed for Developers WP plugin
// http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oauth-twitter-feed-for-developers/

$no_of_tweets = $widget['no_of_tweets'];
$twitter_username = $widget['twitter_username'];
$tweets = getTweets($no_of_tweets, ''.$twitter_username.'');
    if(is_array($tweets)){

// to use with intents
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>';

foreach($tweets as $tweet){

if($tweet['text']){
    $the_tweet = $tweet['text'];

    // i. User_mentions must link to the mentioned user's profile.
    if(is_array($tweet['entities']['user_mentions'])){
        foreach($tweet['entities']['user_mentions'] as $key => $user_mention){
            $the_tweet = preg_replace(
                '/@'.$user_mention['screen_name'].'/i',
                '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$user_mention['screen_name'].'" target="_blank">@'.$user_mention['screen_name'].'</a>',
                $the_tweet);
        }
    }

    // ii. Hashtags must link to a twitter.com search with the hashtag as the query.
    if(is_array($tweet['entities']['hashtags'])){
        foreach($tweet['entities']['hashtags'] as $key => $hashtag){
            $the_tweet = preg_replace(
                '/#'.$hashtag['text'].'/i',
                '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23'.$hashtag['text'].'&src=hash" target="_blank">#'.$hashtag['text'].'</a>',
                $the_tweet);
        }
    }

    // iii. Links in Tweet text must be displayed using the display_url
    //      field in the URL entities API response, and link to the original t.co url field.
    if(is_array($tweet['entities']['urls'])){
        foreach($tweet['entities']['urls'] as $key => $link){
            $the_tweet = preg_replace(
                '`'.$link['url'].'`',
                '<a href="'.$link['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$link['url'].'</a>',
                $the_tweet);
        }
    }

    echo $the_tweet;


    // 3. Tweet Actions
    //    Reply, Retweet, and Favorite action icons must always be visible for the user to interact with the Tweet. These actions must be implemented using Web Intents or with the authenticated Twitter API.
    //    No other social or 3rd party actions similar to Follow, Reply, Retweet and Favorite may be attached to a Tweet.
    // get the sprite or images from twitter's developers resource and update your stylesheet
    echo '
    <ul class="twitter_intents">
        <li><a class="reply" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='.$tweet['id_str'].'"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i>R</a></li>
        <li><a class="retweet" href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='.$tweet['id_str'].'"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i>R</a></li>
        <li><a class="favorite" href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='.$tweet['id_str'].'"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>F</a></li>
    </ul>';


    // 4. Tweet Timestamp
    //    The Tweet timestamp must always be visible and include the time and date. e.g., “3:00 PM - 31 May 12”.
    // 5. Tweet Permalink
    //    The Tweet timestamp must always be linked to the Tweet permalink.
    echo '
    <p class="timestamp">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/YOURUSERNAME/status/'.$tweet['id_str'].'" target="_blank">
            '.date('h:i A M d',strtotime($tweet['created_at']. '- 8 hours')).'
        </a>
    </p>';// -8 GMT for Pacific Standard Time
} else {
    echo '
    <br /><br />
    <a href="http://twitter.com/YOURUSERNAME" target="_blank">Click here to read YOURUSERNAME\'S Twitter feed</a>';
}
}
}    

        // end Twitter output ?>

            </div>

        </section>

    <?php }

} // Class

// Register our widget
// http://docs.layerswp.com/development-tutorials-layers-builder-widgets/#register-and-initialize
register_widget('Layers_Twitter_Widget'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Just figured this out - remembered from a few years back having a similar problem and it was because the no_of_tweets and _username paramteres in the function are documented the wrong way round.

Instead of

```
getTweets($number_of_tweets, $twitter_screenname_to_load);
```

its:

```
getTweets($twitter_screenname_to_load, $number_of_tweets);
```